# Trigger actions on schedule

Tags: struts2

I would need to trigger some action on schedule.
Let's consider this struts.xml :

```
<action name="myAction" class="app.MyAction">
    <result name="success">
        myJsp.jsp
    </result>
</action>
```

this java class :

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

    private String name;

    public getName(){ return name; }

    public setName(String name){ this.name = name }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        Return SUCCESS;        
    }   
}
```

And myJsp :

```
<s:form action="myAction" method="get">
        <s:hidden name="name" value="blabla" />

        <s:submit key="submit"/>
</s:form>
```

Now it would be interesting for me to trigger "myAction" every 30 seconds.
Once the jsp loaded, I'd wait 30 seconds and then the page would refresh.

PS: I don't need some ajax technologies

Comment: So you do want to refresh page not just execute action?

Answer (score 0):

And the winner is... Javascript:

```js
setTimeout(function() { 
    location.reload();
}, 30000);
```